# Converter para JSON objetos de classes que fazem referência recursiva

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando converter para JSON duas listas de classes dististas.

```
public class CustomerItem implements Parcelable {
    //...
    private List<ProductItem> mProductList = new ArrayList<>();
...
}

public class ProductItem implements Parcelable {
   //...
    private List<String> mCustomerList;
//...
}
```

E tenho a seguinte função `onPause()`:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        mJSONProducts = gson.toJson(mBillAccount.getProductItemList());
        mJSONCustomers = gson.toJson(mBillAccount.getCustomerItemList());
        //mBillAccount é objeto da classe BillAccount, que contém as duas listas como membro
        mEditor.putString(KEY_PRODUCT_LIST, mJSONProducts);
        mEditor.putString(KEY_CUSTOMER_LIST, mJSONCustomers);
        /...
        mEditor.apply();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Dentro da minha função `onPause()`, eu converto as listas com o método `gson.toJson(),` para poder resgatá-los ao reiniciar o app. Nesse instante, segundo o monitor de uso de memória, o app vai consumindo crescentemente a memória do celular.

Com o uso do debugger, reparei que nunca é invocada passagem de valor com o método `mJSONCustomers = gson.toJson(mBillAccount.getCustomerItemList());`  Ao reabrir o app, a interface gráfica congela(acredito que congele pois ainda está tentando gerar o JSON). Ao abrir monitor de uso de memória, reparei que a partir desse instante o app vai consumindo a memória em disco gradualmente. Posso abrir mão de salvar o membro `mCustomerList`. Tentei utilizar a notação     `@Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)` sobre este membro, mas também não funcionou.

**EDIÇÃO:**
Quando fiz a pergunta, acreditava que fosse uma recursão cíclica, como se `mCustomerList` fosse da classe `List<CustomerItem>` ao invés de `List<String>`. Foi falta de atenção minha. `mCustomerList` é da classe `List<String>`. Logo, acredito que o problema não seja a recursão cíclica como afirmei anteriormente. Peço desculpas pela confusão.

Comment: Tenta usar esta [lib (LoganSquare)](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare), ela gasta tempo de **compilação**, ao invés de usar tempo de **execução**, pois usa muito pouco de `reflection`, e a questão da interface gráfica que trava, você deve fazer este procedimento em uma outra `thread`, diferente da principal.

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni acredito que o problema não seja bem performance em si. Mas o fato dessas duas classes terem uma dependência cíclica, o que gera uma "recursão infinita" na hora de serializar os objetos.

Comment: @Wakim não vi aonde é está a dependência cíclica, vi que existe o `ProductItem` e o `CustomerItem` apenas tem uma lista de `ProdutcItem`, a classe `ProdutectItem` não faz referencia à `CustomerItem`.

Comment: Acho que foi um erro de digitação, pq o tipo é String, mas o nome do campo é `mCustomerList`, talvez o OP possa tirar essa dúvida. Realmente me guiei pelo relato do OP, mas posso estar enganado mesmo.

Comment: A bom é que fui pelo código e já fiz isso com a lib do LoganSquare e não tive problema, por isso citei ela ali.

Comment: Corrigi a pergunta, peço mil desculpas pela confusão com a classe.